# How to reach $k\cdot 2^{k+2}$ from $(2k)\cdot 2^{k+1}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I was trying to figure out the step between these two equal expression:

$$(2k)\cdot 2^{k+1} = k\cdot 2^{k+2}$$

Comment: Does the "." represent multiplication?

Comment: $(2k)\cdot 2^{k+1}=k(2\cdot 2^{k+1})=k(2^{(k+1)+1})=k\cdot 2^{k+2}$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: that's it!! I was thinking how the k goes out. It is the associative law!! Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT** A number raised to an exponent tells you how many times to multiply that number by itself.

For example: $2^{k}=2*2*...*2$ k-times, so $2*2^{k}=2*(2*2*...*2)$ a total of $k+1$ times so $2*2^{k}=2^{k+1}$